# How does Stack Overflow notify of server-side events without a page reload? I see no request in Firebug

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http, web

How does Stack Overflow show the answer added/edited message without a page reload?

[image]

Yes, I know it will happen with Ajax. So I opened Firebug in a browser to check it, to see whether any requests are coming in a particular interval of time.
But I don't see any request coming in Firebug.

Can we perform a request without it showing in Firebug?
Are there any other ideas behind this or is my concept totally wrong?

Comment: This looks like a question for Meta rather than SO itself.

Comment: AFAIK, they use WebSockets to do that. Not AJAX.

Comment: It is showing in firebug `ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/`

Comment: @JBNizet (just adding) And with websockets, it takes an initial AJAX request to initiate and that's it (that you see in the console). I'm sure if you disabled websockets, you would see multiple AJAX requests either at given periods of time or only when something has updated.

Comment: @Fluffeh I don't think so, the example happens to be stackexchange but the question is about how this is accomplished.

Comment: I am not familar with WebSockets. Basically I am PHP developer. Is there any good tutorials for Websockets that how it is accomplished the request.

Comment: Does not belong on Meta, this is a typical "how does <some site> do <some functionality>" question, it is just a coincidence in this case that the site in question is SO.

Comment: In addition, the biggest advantage of WebSockets is PUSH ! It's easy to do that API. However not all browsers support HTML5 features. Maybe SO is using SignalR : a really powerfull framework to manage communication with new and old browsers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears to be using HTML 5 [Web Sockets](http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/). They basically keep an open connection between the server and the client and, among many other things, allow the client to define event handlers to treat new data when received from the server.

Here you'll find some basic examples and concepts about WebSockets: [Introducing WebSockets: Bringing sockets to the web](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/).

> The WebSocket specification defines an API establishing "socket"
>   connections between a web browser and a server. In plain words: There
>   is an persistent connection between the client and the server and both
>   parties can start sending data at any time.

There is also a [live demo](http://html5demos.com/web-socket) with server & client [source code](http://github.com/remy/html5demos/tree/master/server/) available.

You might also find the following question useful: [How do real time updates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10808924/851811)

Answer (score 3):

To add to [Xavi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12425783/105570), if you want to get started with web sockets without having to understand all the internals, you might try out [Pusher](http://pusher.com/), a library for multiple platforms (including PHP) that makes push notifications on the web very straightforward.

I do not work for Pusher; it's just a product I've found very useful in the past. I've always used the free version for small personal projects, though I would probably pay if I ever used it on a larger application.